Isolated Azure Durable Entity Function never executes
I have created a .net 8 isolated function app as a POC for using durable entities containing a single entity. Also created 2 endpoints, one to retrieve the entity value, the other to act on the entity. When retrieving the value of the entity it is always null. I have left the app running overnight to see if it is a timing issue and the value is still returned as null. I have tried this both running on Azureite as well a storage account in Azure.
The entity function is recognized by the framework but a breakpoint inside the function is never hit.
The code below is scraped directly from the MS documentation on Durable Entities. here
Entity Definition:
 public class Counter : TaskEntity<int>
 {
     readonly ILogger logger;

     public Counter(ILogger<Counter> logger)
     {
         this.logger = logger;
     }

     public void Add(int amount)
     {
         this.State += amount;
     }

     public Task Reset()
     {
         this.State = 0;
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     public Task<int> Get()
     {
         return Task.FromResult(this.State);
     }

     // Delete is implicitly defined when defining an entity this way

     [Function(nameof(Counter))]
     public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] TaskEntityDispatcher dispatcher)
         => dispatcher.DispatchAsync<Counter>();
 }

Function Definitions:
 [Function("GetCounter")]
 public static async Task<HttpResponseData> GetCounter(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "Counter/{entityKey}")] HttpRequestData req,
     [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, string entityKey)
 {
     var entityId = new EntityInstanceId("Counter", entityKey);
     EntityMetadata<int>? entity = await client.Entities.GetEntityAsync<int>(entityId);
     HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(entity?.State);

     return response;
 }


 [Function("AddCounter")]
 public static async Task<HttpResponseData> AddCounter(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "Counter/{entityKey}/add")] HttpRequestData req,
     [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, string entityKey)
 {
     var entityId = new EntityInstanceId("Counter", entityKey);
     await client.Entities.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, "add", 1);
     
     HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     

     return response;
 }


csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


You are accessing entity in your client?

your code is working fine for me. addcounter, getcounter, run

I don't think this is relevant, but just wondered why you've got get as the method for your Add function? Clients will expect get to be idempotent, rather than to mutate something.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I am accessing the entity using the DurableTaskClient via an HTTP call.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya are you running as a .net 8 isolated function app?

@EvanNielsen Just confirming so you accessing entity in another Http call insted of directly calling the entity url?

@EvanNielsen yes

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I am accessing the entity via the same url that you are using in your screenshots.
Can you tell me what version of Visual Studio and what version of the Function Core Tools you are running?

@EvanNielsen Visual studio version is 17.10.0,
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801,
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669
https://i.imgur.com/1X2nDcz.png

@EvanNielsen Cross check, the http request is allowed or not. Check if any firewall is blocking?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I updated VS and core tools to the same version you are running and have the same function runtime version, still no luck. Accessing the entity via the http endpoint always returns null. Firewall is not blocking.
Could you send the versions of nuget packages you are using?

@EvanNielsen could you please add your .csproj file in question

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I updated the post with the csproj

@EvanNielsen I am using DurableTask version 1.1.1

Github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/2830

Your code worked fine for me.
As I mentioned in comment and I am using DurableTask Version 1.1.1.
I tried using 1.1.3  was also facing the similar issue. It is becuase of package support with other packages.
I tried upgrading the other packages also but all throw some error.  Packages are not compatible with each other.
I would suggest using 1.1.1 or 1.1.2, with these versions of other packages.
This Worked for me.
Function.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client.Entities;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Entities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace FunctionApp9
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [Function("GetCounter")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> GetCounter(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "Counter/{entityKey}")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, string entityKey)
        {
            var entityId = new EntityInstanceId("Counter", entityKey);
            EntityMetadata<int>? entity = await client.Entities.GetEntityAsync<int>(entityId);
            HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(entity?.State);

            return response;
        }


        [Function("AddCounter")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> AddCounter(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "Counter/{entityKey}/add")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client, string entityKey)
        {
            var entityId = new EntityInstanceId("Counter", entityKey);
            await client.Entities.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, "add", 1);

            HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);


            return response;
        }

    }
    public class Counter : TaskEntity<int>
    {
        readonly ILogger logger;

        public Counter(ILogger<Counter> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public void Add(int amount)
        {
            this.State += amount;
        }

        public Task Reset()
        {
            this.State = 0;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task<int> Get()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(this.State);
        }

        // Delete is implicitly defined when defining an entity this way

        [Function(nameof(Counter))]
        public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] TaskEntityDispatcher dispatcher)
            => dispatcher.DispatchAsync<Counter>();
    }
}


FunctionApp9.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

OUTPUT:




This seems to be fixed in the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask Version 1.1.4.
